# IdentityServer4 con WebApi 4.6

Tags: seguridad, asp.net-web-api

Estoy montando un Servidor de Identidad con IdentityServer4 (.Net Core) proteja
Web Api  en .Net Framework 4.6.2

Ya logro que proteja la API pero no logro que el token tipo   Bearer
 permita el acceso.

Configuración del Cliente en IdentiyServidor4:

```
 new Client
        {
            ClientId = "mvc",
            ClientName = "MVC Client",
            //AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
            //RequireConsent = true,

            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },

            //RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
            //PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },
             AllowedScopes = { "api2" }

            //AllowedScopes =
            //{
            //    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
            //    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
            //    "api2"
            //},
            //AllowOfflineAccess = true
        }
```

Configurar de Seguridad de la API:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
        //Token Consumption
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);

        // Para obtener más información sobre cómo configurar la aplicación, visite https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {

            AuthenticationType = "oidc",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000", //ID Server SSO Server
            ClientId = "mvc",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            //RedirectUri = "http://localhost:55392/signin-oidc", //URL of Client website
            //PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:55392/signout-callback-oidc", //URL of Client website
            Scope = "api2",
            //AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,

            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

        });

    }
```

Cliente que invoca la API:

```
Console.ReadKey();
        // discover endpoints from metadata
        var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");
        if (disco.IsError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
            return;
        }

        // request token
        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "mvc", "secret");
        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("api2");

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Json);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");

        // call api
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:55392/api/protected");
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        }
        else
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(JArray.Parse(content));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

> Resultado del Cliente:
>   Crea el token pero no encuentra la api:

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjUzNGQzMTM2ZjI3YmJlZDFkODMxNzI4MTA0YWIyNGM3IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1MjcxMTUwNzksImV4cCI6MTUyNzExODY3OSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjpbImh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMC9yZXNvdXJjZXMiLCJhcGkyIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Im12YyIsInNjb3BlIjpbImFwaTIiXX0.jhP9CsldyC_vIKlvJhK9LpcLQW3Y4yJMODVwkJwudioHynl-05y0mEy-BV2OvlU9oNKqXUEWpoTXlwEs8uDVct7Mym9KTjZcc-ORrzUvAdBoW07LN0rukI6WjkKA6UL95JsO_EjZRBtYlGBdkY50p9ijP-9J3r5JTjPKO-0-KhUGzweDnSSTAa_Y8t7Ol3B20_DrDhDOuytFgSDz0ugTOGArABMpJpuM7yeJNrf3yP0j8fKRLHXYmbta2_bNsVXXnT6KhOuy2fDQ7-iLTScdg4sr_uCmHySCSO5rSy83_jZmr0WfUNm7sPmQEHCHO9PFMpl2E-IH7_kThEl5_SXcTQ",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

NotFound

Comment: Hola, puedes poner el código de `public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` de tu Api?

Comment: En la sección esta: Configurar de Seguridad de la API:

Comment: puertos de cada cosa?